# Page Not Found for urls - openwisp-radius

Tags: django, openwisp

I'm new to Django, I am following this guide to setup openwisp-radius
https://openwisp-radius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/setup.html

When I go to the browser for any path from urlpatterns I get Page not found (404).

My django version is 3.0, os is Ubuntu 20.04, I installed openwisp-radius-0.2.1

I created a new django project with django-admin startproject testapp, and added code from the guide to settings.py and urls.py

this is my settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for testapp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '$_u-k638-9hprxb8lhx96+q+yo97be1uriik_86*t3my(s8ux3'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # openwisp admin theme
    'openwisp_utils.admin_theme',
    # all-auth
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    # admin
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # rest framework
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    # registration
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'dj_rest_auth',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
    # openwisp radius
    'openwisp_radius',
    'openwisp_users',
    'private_storage',
    'drf_yasg',
]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'private')


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'openwisp_users.User'
SITE_ID = 1

OPENWISP_RADIUS_FREERADIUS_ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

this is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from openwisp_radius.urls import get_urls

urlpatterns = [
    # ... other urls in your project ...
    # openwisp-radius urls
    path('accounts/', include('openwisp_users.accounts.urls')),
    path('', include('openwisp_radius.urls', namespace='radius'))
]
]
```

after adding code, I executed ./manage.py migrate

My folder structure looks like this:

```
testapp
-manage.py
-db.sqlite3
-testapp
--init.py
--asgi.py
--settings.py
--urls.py
--wsgi.py
```

Comment: What's the URL you are opening in the browser?

Comment: @nemesisdesign http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts,  http://127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Access `http://localhost:8000/admin/` and `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/docs/`
2. Run `./manage.py show_urls` to know all the available URL paths